# Vários UPDATEs usando dados de uma consulta (SELECT)

Tags: vb.net

Tenho esse código para fazer um SELECT que retorna vários registros ou linhas:

```
Public Sub ConsultaFimFerias()
    Dim sqlCmd As String = "SELECT Id FROM tb_ferias WHERE Data2 < '24/03/2020' "
    con = New SqlConnection(strCon.strCon2)
    cmd = New SqlCommand(sqlCmd, con)

    con.Open()
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    Dim result As New ArrayList()
    While dr.Read()
        ' Insert each column into a dictionary
        Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
        For count As Integer = 0 To dr.FieldCount - 1
            dict.Add(dr.GetName(count), dr(count))
        Next
        ' Add the dictionary to the ArrayList
        result.Add(dict)
    End While
    dr.Close()

    For Each dat As Dictionary(Of String, Object) In result
        UpdateSituacaoByFerias(dat) '<----- NÃO SEI O QUE INSERIR AQUI
    Next

End Sub
```

O resultado é:

Id (coluna)

- 194
- 147

Preciso fazer um UPDATE em outra tabela usando os resultados do SELECT, coluna Id.

```
Public Function UpdateSituacaoByFerias(id As Integer)
    strCmdUpdate = "UPDATE tb_funcionarios_ws SET situacao_contrato = '' WHERE id = " & id

    con = New SqlConnection(strCon.strCon2)
    cmd = New SqlCommand(strCmdUpdate, con)

    Try
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Não foi possível concectar ao banco de dados, erro: " & vbCrLf & ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Erro ao concectar")
        Return False
    Finally
        con.Dispose()
        cmd.Dispose()
    End Try
    Return False

End Function
```

Enfim, como posso fazer um UPDATE de cada registro que o SELECT me fornece?

Comment: seu método `VerificaFerias` retorna um boolean, como espera fazer um `For Each` de valores inteiros dele? Precisa ler os valores no `Datareader` e retornar um Array, List, etc, um objeto que seja `IEnumerable` para fazer o foreach.

Comment: veja esse exemplo que é exatamente o que precisa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978127/storing-results-of-a-datareader-into-an-array-in-vb-net

Comment: Obrigado, @RicardoPontual. Como eu faço para realizar o UPDATE com o Dictionary(Of String, Object) ?

Answer (score 1):

Para ajudar a quem precisar:

```
Public Sub ConsultaFimFerias()
    TextBox1.Text = Date.Now.ToShortDateString
    Dim sqlCmd As String = "SELECT Id FROM tb_ferias WHERE Data2 < '" & TextBox1.Text & "' AND SituacaoContrato = 'FERIAS' "
    con = New SqlConnection(strCon.strCon2)
    cmd = New SqlCommand(sqlCmd, con)

    con.Open()
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    Dim result As New ArrayList()
    While dr.Read()
        ' Insert each column into a dictionary
        Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
        For count As Integer = 0 To dr.FieldCount - 1
            dict.Add(dr.GetName(count), dr(count))
        Next
        ' Add the dictionary to the ArrayList
        result.Add(dict)
    End While
    dr.Close()

    For Each dat As Dictionary(Of String, Object) In result
        UpdateSituacaoByFerias(dat.Item("Id"))
    Next

End Sub
```

Depois do SELECT tem a função UPDATE

```
Public Function UpdateSituacaoByFerias(id As String)
    strCmdUpdate = "UPDATE tb_funcionarios_ws SET situacao_contrato = '' WHERE id = " & id

    con = New SqlConnection(strCon.strCon2)
    cmd = New SqlCommand(strCmdUpdate, con)

    Try
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Não foi possível concectar ao banco de dados, erro: " & vbCrLf & ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Erro ao concectar")
        Return False
    Finally
        con.Dispose()
        cmd.Dispose()
    End Try
    Return False

End Function
```